# Linux mint 20: поменять desktop environment для RDP (XRDP) - сессий

Tags: linux, linux-mint, rdp

Господа,

я взял [такой мануальчик](https://techcatalystblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/how-to-easily-setup-remote-desktopxrdp-in-linux-mintubuntu/) и попробовал настроить RDP подключение с машины под Win10 к десктопу, на котором работает Linux Mint 20 Mate.

Всё работает, но вместо моего красивенького mate - десктопа с кучей чепухи появляется окно с крысой посередине (это шутка, но факт остаётся фактом - работает xfce4)

[image: xfce]

Как бы мне сделать, чтобы при установке RDP - сессии запускался мой красивенький mate - десктоп?

Содержимое файла ~/.xsession такое:

```
    xfce4-session
```

Файл /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini - я не трогал.

Буду благодарен за советы.

Comment: дык, ты же написал «запускать xfce», а теперь удивляешься, что запустился xfce?

Comment: А я не знаю, как сказать "запускать mate". Собственно, в этом и был вопрос.

Comment: мм... посмотри название скрипта, который запускает сессию... что-то вроде `start-mate` или `mate-session`... если ничего похожего нет, то можно подсмотреть в поле `Exec` в `*.desktop`-файле в  `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас попробую! Так обидно - я раз в полгода сам решаю эту задау, потом благополучно забываю, что и где правил, и при следующем обновлении опять как дурак сижу и пытаюсь сделать заново.

Comment: Просто не устанавливайте несколько DE на одной машине. Ставьте сразу ту, которая вам нравится. DE это не только WM. К каждой DE прилагается свой набор программ (и демонов), которые почти всегда между собой конфликтуют.

Comment: > Просто не устанавливайте несколько DE на одной машине - я не нашел инструкцию, как с mate настроить RDP. Нашел только ту, которая позволяет установить xfce в качестве "удаленного" DE. Понятно, что разница - в строчке, котрая прописана в файле ~/.xsession - но что это за строка для mate - не знаю :-) Я напишу в комментарии, если у меня получится

Comment: Я не знаю, что в этой инструкции означает 3D и 2D desktop. Это какая-то лабуда. Предположим, что mate - 2D, как и xfce. В таком случае, если у вас уже была установлена mate, значит строчку `sudo apt install xfce4` нужно было просто пропустить, а если ещё не установлена, то установить: `sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment`.

Comment: И если вы отвечаете человеку, который не является автором вопроса в комментариях, то обращайтесь к нему по нику через @, иначе он не получит уведомления.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, спасибо за советы. Сегодня смог проверить. Правда, не всё получилось: 1) при замене в файле ~/.xsession строки "xfce4-session" на "mate-session" я при попытке зайти по RDP получаю ошибку в окне RDP "Could not acquire name on session bus". 2) В файле /usr/share/xsessions/mate.desktop действительноесть строка "Exec=mate-session". В файле /usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop написано Exec=startxfce4. А куда нужно написать это название скрипта? Если у Вас будут еще идеи - я с удовольствием проверю... Скоро дополню вопрос.

Comment: @S.H., похоже это такой квирк на дебианах: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/wiki/Debian-dbus-user-session-package

Comment: @Fat-Zer - о, круто! по крайней мере, понятна причина первой ошибки, можно двигаться дальше! То есть, приколв том, что если кто то залогинен, то не откроется RDP - сессия. Но это - фигня, просто буду разлогиниваться... Сейчас, вооруженный этим знанием, снова попробую.